# How to set path to unrar library in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, rar, unrar

I am using Pycharm as my IDE (Python 3.7) and am trying to extract a password protected .rar file (I know the password) and have imported rarfile from unrar but am getting this error **"LookupError: Couldn't find path to unrar library."**

I also attempted changing my import statement to just say "import rarfile" but instead got the following error  **"rarfile.RarCannotExec: Unrar not installed?"**

I also tried including this line of code, based on something I found in the rarfile documentation: *rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL = "unrar"* however I got the same errors.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
from unrar import rarfile

def hacker(file_path):
    passwords = open('pwds.txt', 'r')
    with rarfile.RarFile(file_path) as file:
        for line in passwords:
            try:
                file.pwd = line
                file.extractall()
            except RuntimeError:
                pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

on different os need different solutions:
on Windows：

1. download the libfile, http://www.rarlab.com/rar/UnRARDLL.exe, install it;
2. you'd better choose the default path, C:\Program Files (x86)\UnrarDLL\
3. the most important is add the environment path, the varname enter UNRAR_LIB_PATH, pay attention, it must be!!!. then if your system is 64bit enter C:\Program Files (x86)\UnrarDLL\x64\UnRAR64.dll, if your system is 32bit enter C:\Program Files (x86)\UnrarDLL\UnRAR.dll.
4. after save the environment path, rerun your pycharm.

on Linux you need to make so file, which is a little difficult.

1. the same, download the libfile http://www.rarlab.com/rar/unrarsrc-5.4.5.tar.gz, you can choose the latest version.
2. after download extract the file get the file unrar, `cd unrar` ,then `make lib`, then `make install-lib`, we'll get file `libunrar.so`(in /usr/lib).
3. last, you also need to set the environment path, `vim /etc/profile` open file `profile`, add `export UNRAR_LIB_PATH=/usr/lib/libunrar.so` in the end of the file. then save the file, use `source /etc/profile` to make the environment successful.
4. rerun the .py file.

the resource website：https://blog.csdn.net/ysy950803/article/details/52939708

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @tom answer for `Windows 10` environment, the following steps should help:

1. Download the libfile via the [link](http://www.rarlab.com/rar/UnRARDLL.exe) and install it.
2. For easy replication the following steps, choose the default path, C:\Program Files (x86)\UnrarDLL\
3. Go to Environment Variables window ([link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)) and selected Advanced.
4. Click Environment Setting.
5. Under the User variables, select New.
6. In the New User Variables, rename the Variable name as **UNRAR_LIB_PATH**
7. To select the Variable Value, select Browse file. Depending on your system,  64bit enter C:\Program Files (x86)\UnrarDLL\x64\UnRAR64.dll, if your system is 32bit enter C:\Program Files (x86)\UnrarDLL\UnRAR.dll.
8. Save the environment path and rerun your Pycharm.

The graphical illustration is as below,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, after you do the things as mentioned by Tom.chen.kang and balandongiv, if you're using a 32bit DLL with 64bit Python, or vice-versa, then you'll probably get an error like this when you try to import unrar:-

> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

In that case do this:

For 32 Python & 32 bit DLL
Change your Environment variables for variable ***UNRAR_LIB_PATH*** to :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\UnrarDLL\UnRAR.dll
```

For 64 bit Python & 64 bit DLL
Change your Environment variables for variable ***UNRAR_LIB_PATH*** to :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\UnrarDLL\x64\UnRAR.dll
```

Restart your Pycharm or other Development Environment.