# Couldn't find path to unrar library in aws lambda (Python)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, unrar

I have a rar file, which I want to unrar in AWS lambda using python. I learned about [unrar](https://pypi.org/project/unrar/) library in python. I have created the layer for [unrar](https://pypi.org/project/unrar/) in AWS. But now when I execute the code

```
from unrar import rarfile
rar = rarfile.RarFile('file.rar')
rar.extractall()
```

I got the following error

```
Couldn't find path to unrar library.
```

I read the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574212/how-to-set-path-to-unrar-library-in-python). According to the solution, I have to set the environment variable. can I use this solution for AWS Lambda also? and what other solutions can be possible.

Comment: How did you install `unrar` (and the `unrar` native library you need to compile by hand) into the AWS Lambda environment..?

Comment: with this command
`docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.7" /bin/sh -c "pip install unrar -t python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/; exit"`
then I zipped it and upload to layer

Comment: So you didn't install the native library at all? That's likely why it isn't there.

Comment: okk! so how to install native unrar library in lambda?

Comment: The library installation instructions are on the unrar PyPI page. Now you'll just have to come up with a build environment that's ABI compatible with Lambda. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @AKX. I figured out, how unrar will work with lambda environment.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I followed documentation of [unrar](https://pypi.org/project/unrar/). Steps I followed

1. download [source file](http://www.rarlab.com/rar/unrarsrc-5.2.6.tar.gz), unzip it. (it will create a folder say **unrar**)
2. cd unrar (go to folder)
3. `make lib && make install-lib`
4. it will create `libunrar.so` file at `/usr/lib` location in linux.

Python unrar could not find this file in Linux path, which is why It was throwing `Couldn't find path to unrar library.`

Now, I created a lambda layer for this file.

1. create a folder named **lib** and copy/paste this **libunrar.so** in that folder.
2. create a zip of **lib** and upload it to a lambda layer
3. attach this layer to your lambda

Finally, set an environment variable in lambda `UNRAR_LIB_PATH` to `libunrar.so`